# Unity Realm, Android build fails "Could not analyze the user's assembly."

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, realm, il2cpp

Just implemented Realm on Unity, using IL2CPP and it works like charm on Editor.
However, upon build on Android, it fails within few seconds, Error message

> Could not analyze the user's assembly. Object reference not set to an instance of an object UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) RealmWeaver.UnityWeaver/UnityLogger:Error (string,Mono.Cecil.Cil.SequencePoint) RealmWeaver.Analytics:AnalyzeUserAssembly (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition) RealmWeaver.Analytics/<>c__DisplayClass9_0:<.ctor>b__2 () System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback ()

I’ve searched all over the place, i found nothing related

I frankly didn't know from where even to start !
I reimported the project
Tried to change the Api compatibility level and Editor assemblies Compatibility
Needless to say, nothing